# Is there a way to save Key-Value pairs in AWS Textract as a JSON or CSV to an S3 Bucket?

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, keyvaluepair, amazon-textract

I am slowly learning things on AWS and Python, and I have been following this example in here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/automatically-extract-text-and-structured-data-from-documents-with-amazon-textract/

More specifically, the Form Extraction bit towards the end.

And I suppose if I am doing the whole process using a Lambda function, where the trigger is an S3 image input, is there a way to save the Key-Value pairs resulting out of the Analyse_Document function as a json or a CSV in the same S3 bucket?

Here is my code:

```
#Loading AWS CLI and Packages
import json
import boto3
import os
import urllib.parse

print('Loading function')

#S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Amazon Textract client
textract = boto3.client('textract')

def getTextractData(bucketName, documentKey):
    print('Loading getTextractData')
    # Call Amazon Textract
    response = textract.analyze_document(
        Document={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': bucketName,
                'Name': documentKey
            }
        },
        FeatureTypes=["FORMS"])

    forms_json = []

    for page in doc.pages:
        for field in page.form.fields:
            print("Key: {}, Value: {}".format(field.key, field.value))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try:
        detectedText = getTextractData(bucket, key)
        writeTextractToS3File(detectedText, bucket, key)

        return 'Processed'

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

I was able to produce a text file before but now as I have changed the code to get a CSV or a JSON (for DynamoDB), I am unable to do that. Help?

Comment: Could you update your question with a code example?

Comment: I have updated the post with my code up there.